# Mysql in not using index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have following table ->

```
 mysql> describe inventoryLineItem;
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                      | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| createdBy               | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dateCreated             | bigint(20)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| isDeleted               | bit(1)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| lastModified            | bigint(20)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastModifiedBy          | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| baseRate                | decimal(19,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| categoryId              | char(20)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| freightRate             | decimal(19,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gstRate                 | decimal(19,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| inventoryLineItemId     | char(20)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| inventoryLineItemStatus | varchar(255)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| inventoryLotId          | char(20)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| meta                    | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| namespace               | varchar(255)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| loadUnloadCharges       | decimal(19,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| preTaxAmountPerUnit     | decimal(19,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| productId               | char(20)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| quantity                | decimal(19,3) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| taxAmountPerUnit        | decimal(19,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| totalGrossValue         | decimal(19,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| unit                    | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| unitRate                | decimal(19,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| otherCharges            | decimal(19,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| normalisedProductName   | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| revisedItem             | bit(1)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and following indexes on this table

```
 mysql> show index from inventoryLineItem;
+-------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table             | Non_unique | Key_name                                        | Seq_in_index | Column_name             | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| inventorylineitem |          0 | PRIMARY                                         |            1 | id                      | A         |        1101 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| inventorylineitem |          0 | UK_4inpuip29bneflv726ko6seix                    |            1 | inventoryLineItemId     | A         |        1090 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| inventorylineitem |          0 | index_inventoryLineItem_inventoryLineItemId     |            1 | inventoryLineItemId     | A         |        1090 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| inventorylineitem |          1 | index_inventoryLineItem_isDeleted               |            1 | isDeleted               | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| inventorylineitem |          1 | index_inventoryLineItem_inventoryLotId          |            1 | inventoryLotId          | A         |         596 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| inventorylineitem |          1 | index_inventoryLineItem_productId               |            1 | productId               | A         |         488 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| inventorylineitem |          1 | index_inventoryLineItem_inventoryLineItemStatus |            1 | inventoryLineItemStatus | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| inventorylineitem |          1 | index_inventoryLineItem_namespace               |            1 | namespace               | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+-----
```

when I am executing the following query it is showing possible keys but not using any keys, why it is not using index

```
mysql> EXPLAIN  SELECT * FROM inventoryLineItem where inventoryLineItemId = 728362543914946859;
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table             | partitions | type | possible_keys                                                            | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | inventoryLineItem | NULL       | ALL  | UK_4inpuip29bneflv726ko6seix,index_inventoryLineItem_inventoryLineItemId | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1101 |    10.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

it is showing in possible keys but not using any keys and type value is All instead of index, please let me know what I am doing wrong or please share any resource which explains it . Thanks in advance .

Comment: How many records does the `inventoryLineItem` table have?

Comment: `mysql> select count(*) from inventoryLineItem;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     1091 |
+----------+
`

Comment: For a table this small, it may not be faster to use the index.  You _do_ have an index which should cover most of the query; this isn't the problem here.

Comment: ok will try with bigger one ,  was trying to learn about indexing , could you please share some resource it will be grateful

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Even on such a small table, I would have expected it to use the index.

Comment: MySQL also may choose to skip the index if it estimates that the condition matches a significantly large portion of the rows. Can you try this query: `SELECT ROUND(SUM(inventoryLineItemId = 728362543914946859) / COUNT(*), 2) AS ratio FROM inventoryLineItem;`

Comment: Your optimizer decided not to use indexes. It preferred ALL(full table scan). @BillKarwin wrote the reason above in the first line(Selectivity ratio). Optimizer does not have the obligation to use indexes to execute query.

Answer (score 0):

This is a serious performance problem:

```
| inventoryLineItemId     | char(20)  

where inventoryLineItemId = 728362543914946859;
```

Comparing a string to an number.  Each row will be read, the string will be converted to a number, then checked against that number (728...)

Plan A:  Put quotes around the number.

Plan B:  Change the column declaration to `BIGINT`.

(Since I don't know the semantics of `inventoryLineItemId`, I can't recommend one versus the other.)

It looks like you have redundant indexes.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.  Then we can discuss the indexes.